# r XML library getNodeSet examples

Tags: xml, r, nodes

I'm trying to get the simple function of `getNodeSet()` in `library(XML)` working in R. I tried the examples given at `?getNodeSet`.

The first lines access the document, but get empty lists as result.

```
library(XML)
doc = xmlTreeParse(system.file("exampleData", "tagnames.xml", +
      package = "XML"), useInternalNodes = TRUE)
getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//b[@status]")
getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//b[@status='foo']")
```

gives empty lists such as this:

```
> getNodeSet(doc, "/doc/b[@status]")
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
> getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//b[@status='foo']")
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet
```

The next lines on the same data however give:

```
els = getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//a[@status]")
sapply(els, function(el) xmlGetAttr(el, "status"))
```

a non-empty list.

```
> getNodeSet(doc, "/doc//a[@status]")
[[1]]
<a status="xyz"/> 

[[2]]
<a status="1"/> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

I can't seem to figure out the difference between the two and when I try and use getNodeSet on my files, it also returns empty sets. It is wierd that the help example would give empty lists anyway. Is it a problem with the function, or can anyone help me understand the difference.

Comment: you didn't transcribe the help examples properly for the `b` tags. they have namespaces you need to deal with. re-read the help examples. if you aren't writing XML, you should also consider using the newer `xml2` package.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, for some reason I had lost the namespaces there. I'm just learning about the namespaces now, and it does work with them. Thanks!